# Google Maps SDK Offline use

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, offline, gmsmapview

In my project i have a `ViewController` in which I show a map (`GMSMapView`) with many markers, at some point i save the coordinates of the markers because I want to show the map with the markers when device is offline. Is it possible using google maps sdk? I've found anything but saving coordinates when you are already offline. This is my code to save coordinates.

```
NSData *json = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objRespuesta.respuestaJSON[@"data"]];
NSLog(@"%@",json);
[OSPUserDefault guardarJson:json conPath:path];
```

But when i get offline i do same as when online but markers are not showing on the map.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Google Maps` offline, but you can add your custom map tiles to show when you are offline.

Comment: Thank @SaintThread. Can you recommend any tutorial for that approach. Thanks.

Comment: @luisjd have a look at this: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Offline%20Maps.html ..if my answer helped you with the original question please mark it as right, I would appreciate it! For alternatives, unfortunately it is a stackoverflow off topic, try searching something about custom map tiles for offline use..when you have a sample code you can rise a question and we will help you with that!